# How to count the column

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

**Table1**' Sample data:

```
ID value1 Value2 value3

001 10 20 30
002 20 10 null
003 10 null null
004 10 null 30
....
```

From the table1, I want to make a coulmn count.

Count of row query

`Select count(*) from table1` 'It will give only row count.

But i need column count, which column value should not be null

Expected output

```
 ID   | totcolumn
-----------------
 001     3
 002     2
 003     1
 004     2
....
```

How to make a query, need query help

Comment: You need to use pivot for this..

Comment: if you have numbered columns in your table, it is usually a design issue where you should split those columns into rows in a new table.  Then you can `COUNT()` those rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a nice opportunity to use UNPIVOT if you are on MS SQL Server 2005 or later. First set up some sample data:

```
create table ColumnCount (
    ID char(3) not null,
    Value1 int,
    Value2 int,
    Value3 int
)

insert into ColumnCount(ID,Value1,Value2,Value3)
select '001',10,20,30
union all select '002',20,10,null
union all select '003',10,null,null
union all select '004',10,null,30
union all select '005',null,null,null
```

I added 005 to the sample data you provided above, to show how to handle the case where all ValueX columns are null.

UNPIVOT "normalizes" the data for you so that you can use COUNT against the rows:

```
select *
from ColumnCount
unpivot (Value for ValueN in (Value1, Value2, Value3)) as upvt

ID  Value   ValueN
001 10  Value1
001 20  Value2
001 30  Value3
002 20  Value1
002 10  Value2
003 10  Value1
004 10  Value1
004 30  Value3
```

Notice that it eliminated the NULL values already, so you do not have to. Unfortunately this means that rows with NULL in all ValueX columns (e.g., ID='005') will not show up if you do a simple count. Instead, gather all ID's in a subquery or CTE like AllIds below:

```
with ColumnsOnRows as (
    select *
    from ColumnCount
    unpivot (Value for ValueN in (Value1, Value2, Value3)) as upvt
),
AllIds as (
    select distinct ID
    from ColumnCount
)
select AllIds.ID, count(distinct Value) as totcolumn
from AllIds
left outer join ColumnsOnRows
on ColumnsOnRows.ID = AllIds.ID
group by AllIds.ID
```

Result:

```
ID  totcolumn
001 3
002 2
003 1
004 2
005 0
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `SUM` as follows:

```
SELECT id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN value1 IS NULL then 0 ELSE 1 END) +
       SUM(CASE WHEN value2 IS NULL then 0 ELSE 1 END) +
       SUM(CASE WHEN value3 IS NULL then 0 ELSE 1 END) AS 'COUNT'
FROM table1
group by id
```

### [**DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/64952)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly what you need is something like this

SELECT ISNULL(Value1, 0) + ISNULL(Value2, 0) + ISNULL(Value3, 0) AS _Sum FROM table1

ISNULL will replace the value with 0 if it is NULL

Comment: This doesn't help, This will sum the values `value1` + `value2` + `value3` not *counting* them, so it will give him `60, 30, 10, 40` respectivley, and the OP doesn't want that.